# if negative or function in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm checking a variable for a present string:

```
check_string() {
    if [[ ! "$FILES" =~ "abcd" ]] || [[ ! "$FILES" =~ "xyz" ]];
    then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}
check_string
```

The problem is that the second condition `[[ ! "$FILES" =~ "xyz" ]]` never gets evaluated.

But when I don't negate it, the second condition gets evaluated `[[ "$FILES" =~ "xyz" ]]`:

```
check_string() {
    if [[ "$FILES" =~ "abcd" ]] || [[ "$FILES" =~ "xyz" ]];
    then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}
check_string
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: what is the contents of `$FILES`? If it doesn't match "abcd" then the `||` will short-circuit (stop processing and skip the xyz comparison) by design.

Answer (score 2):

If the first condition is always true, the second will never be evaluated.

You did not mention the content of `$FILES`, but it seems that `$FILES` is never similar to "abcd" and thus the negation is always true.

Comment: yeah, I guess it's just too hot outside and my brain is melting. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Your test

```
[[ ! "$FILES" =~ "abcd" ]] || [[ ! "$FILES" =~ "xyz" ]]
```

is, due to [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), equivalent to

```
! [[ "$FILES" =~ "abcd" && "$FILES" =~ "xyz" ]]
```

For as long as the string `$FILES` does not match both regular expressions, the test will always be true.

Note too that your function don't have to explicitly return one or zero.  It would be enough with

```
check_string() {
    [[ ! "$FILES" =~ "abcd" ]] || [[ ! "$FILES" =~ "xyz" ]]
}
```

The exit status of a function will be that of the last executed command in the function.

---

If you are operating on a list of *filenames* or pathnames, then don't store them in a string.  This would prevent your script from working with filenames that contain spaces.  Instead use a proper array for storing pathnames.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a logical misunderstanding. It would be goold if you tell what you want to do.

1. return 1 if one of the defined files are missing the list?
2. return 1 if one or all of the defined files are missing the list?
3. return 0 if one or the defined files is found the list?
4. return 0 if all of the defined files is found the list?

Atm I could tell you that both conditions will be executed.

If you put `set -x` in the script, bash will print to you what is evaluated.

```
$ cat check_string.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x
check_string() {
if [[ ! "$FILES" =~ "abcd" ]] || [[ ! "$FILES" =~ "xyz" ]];
then
    return 0
else
    return 1
fi
```

Here are my checks.

```
$ FILES="abcd lmo xyz" ./check_string.sh                 
+ check_string
+ [[ ! abcd lmo xyz =~ abcd ]]
+ [[ ! abcd lmo xyz =~ xyz ]]
+ return 1
$ FILES="abcd lmo" ./check_string.sh    
+ check_string
+ [[ ! abcd lmo =~ abcd ]]
+ [[ ! abcd lmo =~ xyz ]]
+ return 0
$ FILES="lmo xyz" ./check_string.sh
+ check_string
+ [[ ! lmo xyz =~ abcd ]]
+ return 0
$ FILES="abcd" ./check_string.sh
+ check_string
+ [[ ! abcd =~ abcd ]]
+ [[ ! abcd =~ xyz ]]
+ return 0
$ FILES="lmo" ./check_string.sh
+ check_string
+ [[ ! lmo =~ abcd ]]
+ return 0
$ FILES="xyz" ./check_string.sh
+ check_string
+ [[ ! xyz =~ abcd ]]
+ return 0
}
check_string
```

In addition: In my opinion, the conditions could be written a little bit more clear.
Change

```
if [[ ! "$FILES" =~ "abcd" ]] || [[ ! "$FILES" =~ "xyz" ]];
```

to

```
if [[ ! "$FILES" =~ "abcd" || ! "$FILES" =~ "xyz" ]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative implementation (not bash-specific)

```
check_string() {
    case "$1" in  
        *abcd*|*xyz*) return 1 ;;
        *) return 0
    esac
}
check_string "$FILES"
```

Comment: Not _quite_ the same logic as in the question.  This would be the same as `! [[ "$FILES" =~ "abcd" || "$FILES" =~ "xyz" ]]` but note that the user negates both parts separately.

Comment: true, but the OP logic is goofy. Every string is not equal to "x" or not equal to "y"